# How can I train a yolov8 model with multi-gpu and rect=True?

Tags: object-detection, multi-gpu, yolov8

I need to train a YOLOv8 model to detect objects in some extremely flat and elongated images. But I find that 'rect' mode is incompatible with multiple GPUs, it warns me that 'rect' mode is incompatible with Multi-GPUs, setting rect=False.

I try to set augment=True and add one line code of Resize in the **init** function of Albumentations class, but it seems like it's wrong.
So how can I train a YOLOv8 model with 'rect' mode and multiple GPUs, even if I need to modify the source code of ultralytics?
[The added code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSVYd.png)